# Query an application price from the android marketplace

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application which is initially freely downloadable but users need to pay to obtain a special feature. In the absence of an in application purchase, I have come up with another paid application which the users will be prompted pay and download. This paid application does acts like a license key and uses the Android Market Licensing to verify purchase. On successful installation of this application and a positive license check, the special feature on the free application gets enabled.

Now to my question. The price of the paid application (special feature) is expected to change. I need to display this price in my free application. Is there any way that I can query the Android market place to get this price information? I basic idea is to avoid hard coding the price in my free application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A search in google for Android Market API brought this up as the first link.

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

You may want to try using that system. If you would prefer not to use that, another way would be to set up a service on a web server that will host the Application name, package name, and price of each application you have like in some sort of XML setup.

Example:

```
<application id="MyApp">
    <packagename>com.mcnabb.footballfun</packagename>
    <price>$1.99</price>
</application>
```

This is just a hackish arbitrary solution though.